# How, in Swift, do I access a property with dynamic type checking, like Obj-C's id?

Tags: swift, dynamic-typing

I have a function:

```
func logLocalisedDescription(_ error: Any) {
  NSLog(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

I want this to work for [NSError](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nserror) and [SKError](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skerror), both of which have a localizedDescription, but no common superclass or protocol that declares it.

Is there a way to tell the Swift compiler to do run-time rather than compile-time type checking, like Objective-C's id? I tried Any, AnyObject and AnyClass, but none of them worked.

I'm fine with the code failing at runtime if the property doesn't exist.

Please don't suggest retrofitting classes to adopt protocols or other solutions. I'm aware of those. The question is about how to do dynamic typing in Swift.

Answer (score 2):

Use a protocol :)

```
protocol LocalizedDescribable {
    var localizedDescription: String { get }
}

extension NSError: LocalizedDescribable {}
extension SKError: LocalizedDescribable {}

func logLocalizedDescription(_ error: LocalizedDescribable) {
    NSLog(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: Is dynamic typing not possible in Swift, as the question asks?

Comment: @VaddadiKartick It is, in the narrow scope of ObjC messaging on apple platforms. See Rob's answer. But it's a feature that's likely going to be phased out, so I would recommend a simpler, safer approach like this.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking about sending arbitrary Objective-C messages to an object of unknown type. I would call that dynamic messaging rather than dynamic type checking. In Objective-C, there are ways to make any object handle any message, regardless of the object's type.

Swift (on Apple platforms) allows you to do Objective-C-style dynamic messaging to `AnyObject`, as documented under [“Accessing Objective-C Methods and Properties” in the `AnyObject` reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/anyobject). In this case, here's the syntax:

```
func logLocalizedDescription(_ error: Any) {
    if let d = (error as AnyObject).localizedDescription as String? {
        NSLog("%@", d)
    }
}
```

I had to explicitly specify the type of the message here to avoid an “Ambigious use of 'localizedDescription'” error, because there are multiple definitions of `localizedDescription` with different types (most are `String`, but `Progress.localizedDescription` is `String!`).

However, you don't need to use dynamic messaging in this particular case. The preferred Swift way, in this case, is to use `as? Error`, like this:

```
func logLocalizedDescription(_ error: Any) {
    if let error = error as? Error {
        NSLog("%@", error.localizedDescription)
    } else {
        NSLog("unknown error: %@", String(describing: error))
    }
}
```

As it happens, `SKError` already conforms to `Error`, although it's not documented to do so. The above function will print an `SKError`'s `localizedDescription`.

If you don't want to rely on this undocumented conformance, you can explicitly make it conform:

```
extension SKError: Error { }
```

Since `Error` declares `localizedDescription`, and `SKError` already implements `localizedDescription`, this retroactive conformance requires no implementation of its own.

Note also that it's inappropriate to pass an unknown string (like an error's `localizedDescription`) as the first argument of `NSLog`, because the first argument of `NSLog` is a format string. If the string contains unexpected `%` characters, the runtime behavior is undefined.